# download a pdf file from internal storage to device ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android-studio, pdf

I have in the internal storage of the app  pdf file, and i have an Entity in my Room database with a String field that contains the path of of the file (without the part about getFilesDir).
I want to get that file and download it (or at least simulate it) on the download directory of the user phone. some can help me?

Entity Room:

```
@Entity(tableName = "ChapterManga")
public class ChapterMangaEntity {
    //campi tabella
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @NonNull
    private int idChapter;
    @NonNull
    private int chapterNumber;
    @NonNull
    private String chapterTitle;
    @NonNull
    private String pdfChapter;
    @NonNull
    public int mangaId;

    //costruttore
    public ChapterMangaEntity(int idChapter, int chapterNumber, String chapterTitle,String pdfChapter, int mangaId){
        this.idChapter = idChapter;
        this.chapterNumber = chapterNumber;
        this.chapterTitle = chapterTitle;
        this.mangaId = mangaId;
        this.pdfChapter = pdfChapter;
    }

    //getter dei campi
    public int getIdChapter() { return idChapter; }
    public int getChapterNumber() { return chapterNumber; }
    public String getChapterTitle() { return chapterTitle; }
    public int getMangaId() { return mangaId; }
    public String getPdfChapter() { return pdfChapter; }
```

i tried to do a copy of the file and put it in download directory, it runs but i cant find nothing on my device and in this way i think i dont have the possibility to notify the user for example with the downloading notification

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardChapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CardItemChapter currentCardItemChapter = cardItemChapterList.get(position);
        holder.txtChapterNumber.setText("Chapter N°" + currentCardItemChapter.getChapter().getChapterNumber());
        holder.txtChapterTitle.setText(currentCardItemChapter.getChapter().getChapterTitle());

        holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sharePref.saveChosenIdChapter(activity.getApplicationContext(),currentCardItemChapter.getChapter().getIdChapter());
               //File pdf = MyUtils.getPdfFromPath(currentCardItemChapter.getChapter().getPdfChapter(),activity.getApplicationContext());
                if(activity.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                    activity.requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_READ_STORAGE);

                }else {
                    MyUtils.startDownloading(activity.getApplicationContext(),currentCardItemChapter.getChapter().getPdfChapter(),currentCardItemChapter.getChapter().getChapterTitle());

                }
            }
        });
```

```
public static void startDownloading(Context context,String pathFile, String chapterTitle){
        String destinationFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        String destinationFilePath = destinationFolderPath + File.separator + chapterTitle + ".pdf";

        try{
            File sourceFile = new File(pathFile);
            File destinationFolder = new File(destinationFolderPath);

            //verifica se il file di destinazione esiste gia
            if(!destinationFolder.exists()){
                destinationFolder.mkdirs();
            }

            File destinationFile = new File(destinationFilePath);

            //copia il file dal percorso di origine a quello di destinazione
            copyFile(sourceFile,destinationFile);

            //aggiorna la galleria multimediale
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,new String[]{destinationFilePath},null,null);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void copyFile(File source, File destination) throws IOException{
        InputStream in =new FileInputStream(source);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ){
            out.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

UPDATE
i want i general make an app to read manga. i have crated the pdf file onmy pc and put that on data/data/com.example.projectname/files/manga and save in the entity field the path /manga/namemanga/file.pdf
eventually there is another way to get the pdf on my app and then when i press a button download the pdf file on my device?